# Why is ‘aus’ needed at the end of a sentence? - More generally: why does a seemingly unnecessary preposition appear at the end of a sentence?

Tags: preposition, separable-verb

I am new to German and have searched for my question but couldn’t find any similar questions that explained why *aus* would appear at the end of a sentence.

Anyway, I’m learning German on Duolingo and a sentence that I have come across is

> Er sieht klein aus.

to mean

> He looks small.

and I don’t quite understand why there is a preposition at the end of the sentence. Is the *aus* necessary? Seems to me like the sentence is saying

> He looks good out

which just sounds weird.

Comment: Similar phenomena in English [split infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive), [stranded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding) and [sentence-ending preposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ending_a_sentence_with_a_preposition).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, the *aus* is not a preposition, but a **prefix** to a *trennbares Verb*, a dividable/seperable verb.

In your example, the english verb *to look* translates to ***aussehen*** which is the verb *sehen* with a prefix *aus*. In present tense, these verbs are conjugated like this

> - ich sehe nett **aus**
> - du siehst nett **aus**
> - er/sie/es sieht nett **aus**
> - wir sehen nett **aus**
> - ihr seht nett **aus**
> - sie sehen nett **aus**

meaning that the prefix slides to the **end** of the sentence.

Read more [here](https://coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/v_04.html) about dividable verbs.

Comment: The closest thing to German [separable verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb) in English are [(particle) phrasal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) like "give up" or "stand out", where the trailing particle fundamentally changes the meaning of the verb. The main difference is that, in English, the particles generally remain separate even in the infinitive, rather than becoming prefixes of the verb root (although they can do so in some derived forms, e.g. "bring up" -> "upbringing").

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is needed. In effect, the verb "aussehen" is split into "aus" and "sehen", wrapping around the adverb, which is also the reason why you can't simply drop the "aus".

You might also want to note the conjugation of "aussehen":

- ich sehe aus
- du siehst aus
- er/sie/es sieht aus
- wir sehen aus
- ihr seht aus
- sie sehen aus

That might make it clearer and more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding

> Is the aus necessary?

Yes it is. Simplifying it to

> Er sieht klein

wouldn't be a valid german sentence.

I hope someone else can add some more informations into this to fit your needs.